# Passing from a set of generators to a set of homogeneous generators

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals, graded-rings

Consider a graded ring $R=R_0\oplus R_1\oplus\dots$. Suppose the irrelevant ideal $R_1\oplus R_2\oplus \dots$ is finitely generated. How come we can assume that it is generated by a finite number of homogeneous elements? I'm not satisfied with the answer "by taking homogeneous parts". I have this example in mind: $(x^2+x)$ is strictly contained in the ideal generated by its homogeneous parts $(x,x^2)$. Of course in this case the irrelevant ideal of the polynomial ring isn't finitely generated, but why can't the same situation be true for finitely generated irrelevant ideals?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $I$ be the irrelevant ideal.  Notice that if $x\in I$, then every homogeneous part of $x$ is in $I$.  Indeed, by definition of $I$, every nonzero homogeneous part of $x$ must have positive degree, and thus be in $I$.  So, we can indeed just take the homogeneous parts of a set of generators for $I$.

So to be clear, the claim here is not that you can always just take the homogeneous parts of a set of generators for an ideal to get a homogeneous set of generators for the same ideal.  Rather, we can do this specifically for the irrelevant ideal because it has the special property that if $x\in I$, every homogeneous part of $x$ is also in $I$.